# How to format a string inside an array?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var columnNames = dt.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(column => "\"" + column.ColumnName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"")
    .ToArray();
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   var fields =   row.ItemArray
        .Select(field => "\"" + field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"")
        .ToArray();
   sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
```

in `row[1]` and `row[2]` these are dates, I want them to be in this format

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff}", row[1]);
```

How should i do that?

Comment: here is some pseudo logic: if it only ever is row[1] and row[2] then add a temp counter outside of the for loop, and inside, keep a score of the current row. if the currentRow == 1 or 2 then you know to do your string formatting there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an overload of [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a function of the value and the index as a parameter; you can use this to apply a different formatting based on the index. The following sample shows a function that formats the value. This function is used in the Select in your code:

```
private string FormatStringByIndex(object field, int index)
{
    if (index > 0 && index < 3)
        return string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff}", field);}
    else
        return field.ToString();
}

// ...

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => "\"" + column.ColumnName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   var fields =   row.ItemArray.Select((field, index) => "\"" + FormatStringByIndex(field, index).Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
   sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
```

Comment: @KGSosa If it solved your problem, please select it as the accepted answer (green tick)

Answer (score 0):

If the column contains `DateTime` type then just do this.

```
var formatted = ((DateTime)row[1]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
```

otherwise you need to convert it to `DateTime` first, then call `DateTime.ToString(format)`.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `foreach` loop, you could do something like this:

```
var dateFormat = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff}";

var dateColumns = new[] { 1, 2 };

var fields = itemArray.Select((e, i) =>
{
    if (dateColumns.Contains(i))
        return String.Format(dateFormat, e);

    return e.ToString();
});
```